# using ngRepeat to display json call

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to display a json format that I get in a restful call, and this is the format of the json call :

```
[
    {
        "codeOffre": 1,
        "titre": "Offre_JEE",
        "niveauExperience": "débutant",
        "description": "besoin Ingénieur Cobol",
        "dateExpiration": 1477004400000,
        "typeContrat": {
            "codeContratType": 2,
            "titre": "CDD"
        },
        "associationCandidatOffres": [],
        "dateDemmaarge": null
    },
    {
        "codeOffre": 2,
        "titre": "Offre_JEE",
        "niveauExperience": "débutant",
        "description": "besoin d'un développeur java/jee",
        "dateExpiration": 1501804800000,
        "typeContrat": {
            "codeContratType": 4,
            "titre": "Stage"
        },
        "associationCandidatOffres": [],
        "dateDemmaarge": null
    },
    {
        "codeOffre": 3,
        "titre": "Système et réseaux",
        "niveauExperience": "4 ans",
        "description": "Besoin Ingénieur System et réseaux",
        "dateExpiration": 1468450800000,
        "typeContrat": {
            "codeContratType": 2,
            "titre": "CDD"
        },
        "associationCandidatOffres": [],
        "dateDemmaarge": null
    }
]
```

in my html page I have this :

```
<ul id="myList" ng-repeat="o in offres">
              <li>
                    <h4><a href="#">{{o.titre}}</a></h4>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

and this is my controller :

```
capValueRecruitApp.controller('offresController', function($scope, offresFactory) {

  offresFactory.getList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.offres = new Array(data);
    console.log($scope.offres);
  }, function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  });

});
```

the `console.log($scope.offres);` displays this :

[image]

but in the index page I get nothing, so I tried to use a static table instead which worked, and here is the code I tried :

```
capValueRecruitApp.controller('offresController', function($scope, offresFactory) {

  offresFactory.getList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.offres=['Jani','Hege','Kai'];
  }, function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
offresFactory.getList().then(function(result) {
    $scope.offres = result.data;
    console.log($scope.offres);
}, 
function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
});
```

When you use .then() the object returned contains a data property that has your actual json data.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong use `new Array` here.

```
offresFactory.getList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.offres = data;//or data.data, this depends on what return getList
    console.log($scope.offres);
```

Answer (score 0):

As i see **on your firefox console**, you return a **data** array from the server to your client, so you can get the array data like so :   `$scope.offres = data.data;`